# Change Google Finance Result from row to column in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language, google-finance

I am pulling data from google finance to google sheet using below formula:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:AAPL","price",TODAY()-10,TODAY())
```

and the result is like below

[image: pic]

what i want the result to be like is below so that when i put new stock in next row result show be like below

[image: pic2]

is there any google sheet expert who can help me as i am new to google sheet and searching on internet haven't haven't me any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paste this in B1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SEQUENCE(1, 10, TODAY()-9, 1), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

[image]

and this in B2 and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(HLOOKUP(B$1:K$1, TRANSPOSE(TEXT(
 GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:"&A2, "price", TODAY()-10, TODAY()), 
 {"dd/mm/yyyy", "@"})), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

to exclude weekend you can do:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TEXT(SEQUENCE(10, 1, TODAY()-9, 1), 
 {"dd/mm/yyyy", "ddd"}), "where not Col2 matches 'Sat|Sun'")), 1)
```

[image]

however to exclude holidays it needs to be done like this:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TEXT(SEQUENCE(10, 1, TODAY()-9, 1), 
 {"dd/mm/yyyy", "ddd"}), 
 "where not Col2 matches 'Sat|Sun' 
    and not Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, M2:M)&"'")), 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you its working but is there a way to change date for both formula at same time and is there a way to ignore holidays as well

Comment: thank you its works. last question how do i change data like if i want stock price of last 30 days from today. what value i have to change, please share screenshot.

Comment: in B2 formula you change range `B$1:K$1` to include 30 columns and `TODAY()-10` to `TODAY()-30`

Comment: in B1 formula you change `SEQUENCE(10, 1, TODAY()-9` to `SEQUENCE(30, 1, TODAY()-29`